# How to force termination of regex search after match is found?

Tags: regex

I have a line:

`hostname = "serv1.namespace.com",` and the regex: `^\s*hostname[A-Z]*\s=?\s"?(.*?)"?,?$`.

This works as desired for the most part (I want the information in quotes), however if I add any character at the end of the string, including a space, then everything beyond the first `"` is added to the match group. Is there a way to force the match group to *only* be what is in the quotes, and to essentially just stop searching after the `",` is encountered?

*edit*: if someone has a better title for this, by all means...

Comment: Look at non-greedy matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop searching after the first quote is found, use `[^\"]*` in place of reluctant dot-star `.*?`. This way the engine will stop after finding the closest doublequote. You will also prevent potential [*catastrophic backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

```
^\s*hostname[A-Z]*\s=?\s"?([^\"]*)"?,?$
```